# How to access a variable from another class?

Tags: ios, xcode

How to access a variable 'pew' from another class (ViewController)?

// ImageTouched.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ImageTouched : UIImageView    
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *pew;    
@end
```

// ImageTouched.m

```
#import "ImageTouched.h"

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    NSLog(@"Image Touched");
    self.pew = @"pewpewpewew";  
}
```

// myViewController.m

```
#import "ImageTouched.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    ImageTouched *instance = [[ImageTouched alloc] init];        
    NSLog(@"Pew value is %@", instance.pew);

}
```

Comment: @SpaceInvader I am under the impression that this is your first time working with code. I would suggest you read a book about coding first, preferably one about C. (not objective-C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a property in your ImageTouched.h header file. You can also define a getter in the header file, essentially it works the same. When you define a property or method in the header file it is made "public" and can be accessed by other classes.

In your header file use something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *pew;
```

Somewhere in ImageTouched.m you have to assign a value to pew, e.g.:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{    
    NSLog(@"Image Touched");
    self.pew = @"pewpewpewew";
}
```

Then in your view controller create an instance:

```
ImageTouched *instance = [ImageTouched init] alloc];
```

then you can acess the property like this:
`instance.pew`

Example:

```
NSLog(@"Pew value is %@", instance.pew);
```

The other option is to use a getter method in the header file.
In your header, declare:

```
- (NSString *)pew;
```

In the implementation (.m) file put:

```
- (NSString *)pew
{
   return self.pew;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but for some reason does not work.
log:
`Pew value is (null)
Image Touched`

Comment: @SpaceInvader you are probably accessing it before initializing it. You can use the getter method described and check if pew == nil then return an empty or error string.

Comment: @RedSerpent I get access to `instance.pew` in `viewDidLoad` (myViewController)

Comment: @SpaceInvader you can access the variable from anywhere but it does not necessarily mean it is initialized.

Comment: @RedSerpent can the problem is that the variable is initialized after clicking on the image?

Comment: @SpaceInvader Cannot tell from your question. You did not provide the code for where and when are you accessing the variable.

Comment: @RedSerpent i changed the first post. Please look at the code.

Comment: You use FullImageTouched instance, not ImageTouched

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the variable `pew` before you initialize it. The `viewDidLoad` method is one of the first methods that gets called when a view controller gets focus. Here is the order of the methods called:

```
-(void)initWithCoder
-(void)awakefromNib    //(if story board is used)
    or
-(void)loadView----() //if manually generating the view contoller

-(void)viewDidLoad-----(called only once in the life cycle of viewController)
-(void)viewWillAppear
-(void)viewDidAppear
```

The `touchesBegan` method is called after the view finish loading. As I said in a comment in edwardmp answer. You need to initialize the variable first. You can either initialize it in the constructor of the ImageTouched class, or by implementing one of the methods that precedes the call for `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I have tried all methods (initWithCoder, awakefromNib, loadView, viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear). They do not work in my case. Or am I doing something wrong ...